# Starting a new fragment from custom dialog doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, fragment

I used to work (mostly for fun) with android couple months ago, and i don't remember it well. I want to ask how to start new Fragment from custom dialog. I am trying, but I am getting errors.
I hadn't used fragments a lot, and now when i restarted with it i don't remember it well, so I'm not sure if it is my silly mistake, or it's real problem.
Fragment doesn't start even for first time, so i couldn't even chceck how it behaves for couple uses

```
09-13 11:10:00.201 22975-22975/com.example.damianadamski.Service E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.damianadamski.Service, PID: 22975
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2114)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
        at com.example.damianadamski.service.ProjectStuff.CustomDialog$1.onDateSet(CustomDialog.java:138)
        at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:171)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:177)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

That's the whole code:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    public static final String TAG = "CustomDialog";
    Context context;
    TextView accept, cancel;
    ImageView imageView;
    CheckBox acceptCheck, cancelCheck;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Intent intent;
    String IdHolder, streetHolder, cityHolder;
    AppCompatActivity activity = new AppCompatActivity();

    public CustomDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        intent = new Intent(context, taskActivity.class);
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("DATA", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        accept = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCancel);
        cancel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonDownload);
        acceptCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.accceptCheck);
        cancelCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cancelCheck);


        accept.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        accept.setOnClickListener(this);
        acceptCheck.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancelCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == acceptCheck.getId()){
            if(acceptCheck.isChecked()) {
                cancel.setClickable(false);
                cancelCheck.setChecked(false);
                cancel.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.ocean));
                accept.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.forestGreen));
                accept.setClickable(true);
            }else{
                accept.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.ocean));
                accept.setClickable(false);
            }


        }
        if(v.getId() == cancelCheck.getId()){
            if(cancelCheck.isChecked()) {
                accept.setClickable(false);
                acceptCheck.setChecked(false);
                accept.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.ocean));
                cancel.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.cornellRed));
                cancel.setClickable(true);
            }else{
                cancel.setTextColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.ocean));
                cancel.setClickable(false);
            }

        }
        if(v.getId() == accept.getId()){

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext());
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor issueEditor = prefs.edit();

                    String id = prefs.getString("id", "");issueEditor.putInt("year", year);
                    if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        Log.e(TAG, "ID puste, dane nie dotarły SharedPreferences");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Błąd przesyłania danych", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }else{

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        TaskFragment taskFragment = new TaskFragment();

                        bundle.putString("id", id);
                        bundle.putString("street", prefs.getString("street", ""));
                        bundle.putString("city", prefs.getString("city", ""));
                        bundle.putInt("year", year);
                        bundle.putInt("month", month);
                        bundle.putInt("day", dayOfMonth);

                        taskFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                        //FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.add(R.id.mainActivity, taskFragment, "TaskFragment");
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        //transaction.replace(R.id.taskFragment, taskFragment);
                        transaction.commit();

                    }

                }
            });
            //new dnew ialog with datepicker
        }
        if(v.getId() == cancel.getId()){

            dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
}
```

Comment: plz show all your code

Comment: The Problem is here `AppCompatActivity activity = new AppCompatActivity();`

Comment: So how can i get to the getSupportFragmentManager() method? I added whole code of CustomDialog

Comment: I've finally created new activity as holder for my new fragment, now it works fine. Sorry for duplication.